# Unreal Engine 4.26.1 - Randomize behavior tree and creating behavior tree via BP or C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, behavior-tree

I'd want to randomize the nodes inside a tree to create a random tree and I'd also want to create nodes by nodes my trees via BP/C++ during runtime. I'm planning on using Genetic Programmation to make trees evolve. But it doesn't seems to be possible via BP. If that's true I'd like to know if there's a way to do that using C++ and if there's one how to do it. I've absolutely no knowledge about C++ in UE but I already know C++ quite well.

Comment: Can I safely assume this question has nothing to do with British Petroleum?

Comment: I didn't even know what it was just a moment ago x)